# json decode returning empty array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve an array from an API, but every time it is returning an empty array after every attempt.

This is my coding which is fetching data from api:

```
<?php
$array=array("name"=>"name1");

$url = "http://getsjobs.esy.es/registerapi.php?".http_build_query($array);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($json,true);

if (is_array(json_decode($data )) || is_object(json_decode($data)))
{ echo 'array exists'; }
else { echo 'Not an array'; }

?>
```

this is my api code

```
  <?php
if(isset($_GET['Array'])) {
    $array = $_GET['Array'];
    header('Content-type: application/json');
}

?>
```

Even if i use `json_encode($array)`. It is returning empty array. I can receive single value or single array element, but not able to send and receive entire 
array from json.

I am not able to find any relevant post. Any link or suggestion will be helpful

Comment: What is this:
$array = [
    'Array[Phone]' => 123456,
    'Array[name]' => 'name1',
];

Comment: i am not getting , I created array of items

Comment: removed the typo error

Comment: Is this a proper format ?

Comment: if you are sure you are putting a json string into `json_decode` then you can call this `echo json_last_error_msg ();` to see if the json is improperly formatted.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: i put that , show no error

Comment: i also put echo json_encode( $out ); after header('Content-type: application/json'); in api .. still array is empty

Comment: even this code """" header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('text' => 'abcd')); """ is not working

Comment: `If` condition will not satisfy in api code as your not sending `Array` in request. instead you should for check for `name`

Comment: can you please suggest some code

Answer (score 0):

My PHP is rusty, but the problem looks to me to be because your API is looking for a parameter called "Array", but nowhere in your calling block does it actually send a GET parameter called "Array".

Your code looks a bit incomplete, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

look here: you're decoding it twice.

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);

if (is_array(json_decode($data )) || is_object(json_decode($data)))
{ echo 'array exists'; }
else { echo 'Not an array'; }
```

simply:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);

if (is_array($data ))
{ echo 'array exists'; }
else { echo 'Not an array'; }
```

if it still doesn't works, see what `echo json_last_error_msg();` returns.
Try to check if your `$json` is a valid json too. Check if what `echo $json;` returns is valid here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/